# Looking for tactical Sicilian lines besides the Dragon and Najdorf

Tags: opening, tactics, sicilian-defense

I am looking for a tactical Sicilian. But I don't want a really popular line like the Najdorf or Dragon that has been analyzed to death.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you are good enough that the Najdorf/Dragon/[insert feared opening variation] being "analysed to death" might actually matter in your practical play, you know better than to ask such questions.

Comment: @Annatar The analysed to death is not a practical concern but what I meant was that the dragon is so forcing that you have got to know like 20 moves to prove your edge and in the najdorf there are so many variations that you can probably reach age 80 without completing study of all of them

Comment: But that's the point - until you reach a certain level, you don't have to study all these variations to depth. Most of your opponents of matching strength will also have matching opening "knowledge", *they* won't know these 20 forcing moves either. Or even 10.

Comment: I know people who do play the Najdorf or the Dragon at club level (around 1500 FIDE Elo) and they do fine even though they don't even know a fraction of the theory of these openings (and that's not even talking about the 1 e4 players who also have to be ready for the Frenchs and Caro-Kanns and so on, so they have even less capacity for Sicilian master theory).

Comment: It is hard to name a good opening which hasn't been analyzed in depth. When I saw your question, the Pelikan (aka Sveshnikov) variation popped to mind -- but that has certainly been analyzed in depth as well.

Comment: This strikes me as opinion-based in the same way as [Rep Suggestions for Petrosian System in Gruenfeld](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35552/rep-suggestions-for-petrosian-system-in-gruenfeld).

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the [Kveinis variation](https://www.chess.com/openings/Sicilian-Defense-Kveinis-Variation). I play it, and it is a good and surprising variation, with a lot of tactical traps.