# Rep Suggestions for Petrosian System in Gruenfeld

Tags: opening, 1.d4, grunfeld-defense, repertoire

I was wondering what people suggest against the Petrosian System in the Gruenfeld.  I'm "club strength" and am just starting to learn the Gruenfeld.  I'm especially curious about this c5-b5-b4 system; do white players fear this one, or are they eager to see it?

I mean this one: https://lichess.org/study/QuiAxqOj/eOVSjyxf

The main line with Ne4 seems really complicated and has a lot of branches, and the engine is recommending all sorts of novelties for white along the way so I'm a bit scared to go for it.  Is there a simpler system to play, besides the c6 line (which I don't think is very good)?

Comment: This is not a discussion site. It is a Q&A site where the questions have correct answers, not opinion based answers.

Comment: I am a bit surprised with the fast closing of this question. Asking "opinions" about opening variations is very common on C.SE and answers are generally constructive. The two questions in the body ("are White players afraid of this system?" and "are there other options than Ne4 and c6 ?") are answerable in objective fashion. That said, the question can be improved : @johnsamples , please give us the moves (and if you know how to, a diagram) leading to the starting position you want us to consider (not only a link to lichess) and short variations for the different options you are considering...

Comment: I don't agree it's a opinion-based question. Please reopen.

Comment: @Evargalo Questions like this have attracted decent-quality answers but they are absolutely inherently discursive questions (and I do not think the fact that some users can pontificate wisely on any topic, and provide value, ratifies the content of the question they respond to with their insights, however deep the answer may be). "Are White players afraid of this system" - since no-one can be expected to speak to the psychology of players in general in a given scenario, this is subjective. He then asks not for objective alternatives but "simpler" ones.

Comment: Because both 'what makes a position scary' and 'what makes a line simple' are rather hard to pin down, the question has strong discursive vibes (since people will find different things scary and simple!). Now, such questions tend to receive responses that ignore what the question really asks and just open-endedly provide some thoughts on the opening and possible lines. But however interesting those thoughts are, Chess.SE may not be the place for essays that do not answer the specific question.